# Why does Spark fail with "No File System for scheme: local"?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to submit Spark job onto the Spark Cluster which is setup on AWS EKS as

```
NAME                            READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
spark-master-5f98d5-5kdfd       1/1     Running             0          22h
spark-worker-878598b54-jmdcv    1/1     Running             2          3d11h
spark-worker-878598b54-sz6z6    1/1     Running             2          3d11h
```

i am using below manifest

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: spark-on-eks
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: spark
          image: repo:spark-appv6
          command: [
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            "/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit \
            --master spark://192.XXX.XXX.XXX:7077 \
            --deploy-mode cluster \
            --name spark-app \
            --class com.xx.migration.convert.TestCase \ 
            --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=repo:spark-appv6
            --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=spark-pi \
            --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark-pi \
            --conf spark.executor.instances=2 \
            local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/testing-jar-with-dependencies.jar"
          ]
      serviceAccountName: spark-pi
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

and getting below error log

```
20/12/25 10:06:41 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'driverClient' on port 34511.
20/12/25 10:06:41 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /192.XXX.XXX.XXX:7077 after 37 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
20/12/25 10:06:41 INFO ClientEndpoint: Driver successfully submitted as driver-20201225100641-0011
20/12/25 10:06:41 INFO ClientEndpoint: ... waiting before polling master for driver state
20/12/25 10:06:46 INFO ClientEndpoint: ... polling master for driver state
20/12/25 10:06:46 INFO ClientEndpoint: State of driver-2020134340641-0011 is ERROR
20/12/25 10:06:46 ERROR ClientEndpoint: Exception from cluster was: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: local
java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: local
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getHadoopFileSystem(Utils.scala:1853)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:737)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:535)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner.downloadUserJar(DriverRunner.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner.prepareAndRunDriver(DriverRunner.scala:177)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner$$anon$2.run(DriverRunner.scala:96)
20/12/25 10:06:46 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
20/12/25 10:06:46 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-d568b819-fe8e-486f-9b6f-741rerf87cf1
```

**Also when i try to submit job in client mode without container parameter, it gets submitted successfully but job keeps runnings and spins multiple executors on worker nodes.**

Spark version- 3.0.0

**When used k8s://http://Spark-Master-ip:7077 \ i get following error**

```
20/12/28 06:59:12 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
20/12/28 06:59:12 INFO SparkKubernetesClientFactory: Auto-configuring K8S client using current context from users K8S config file
20/12/28 06:59:12 INFO KerberosConfDriverFeatureStep: You have not specified a krb5.conf file locally or via a ConfigMap. Make sure that you have the krb5.conf locally on the driver image.
20/12/28 06:59:13 WARN WatchConnectionManager: Exec Failure
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
        at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:354)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:226)
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:215)
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:127)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.intercept(BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.java:134)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.ImpersonatorInterceptor.intercept(ImpersonatorInterceptor.java:68)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.lambda$createHttpClient$3(HttpClientUtils.java:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:257)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:201)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please help with above requirement, Thanks

Comment: what's that `spark://192.XXX.XXX.XXX:7077`? why not `k8s://https://...` ?

Comment: @ItayB i tried and tested with same, i get some other error in logs, i have updated my ask - i tried with http not https - with https i get same but with javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're **not** using [spark on k8s operator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator) the master should be:

```
k8s://https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
```

if not, you can get your master address by running:

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443
```

**EDIT**:
In spark-on-k8s [cluster-mode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#cluster-mode) the `k8s://<api_server_host>:<k8s-apiserver-port>` should be provided (note that adding the port is must!)

In spark-on-k8s the role of "master" (in spark) is played by kubernetes itself - which is responsible to allocate resources for running your driver and workers.

Comment: using above k8s://https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local ( i replaced with my namespace - kubernetes.spark-pi.svc.cluster.local ), i get java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.spark-pi.svc.cluster.local: Name or service not known, please let me know if i am missing correct config

Comment: keep the `default` - not your namespace - that's the something related to kubernetes - and not to your app

Comment: ok, but technically how it is linked to my spark-master pod, i am missing some key-point here, when i will use (k8s://https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local) same  in my spark-submit command how my spark-master and worker will come in use ?

Comment: @Zester07 I've updated my answer, please try the second option if the first one doesn't work. Again, the `master` address has nothing to do with your spark namespace/app - in spark-on-k8s - the k8s will manage the resources for you and you don't need spark master machine/container

Comment: ok, i got it, so what i understood, i don't need any Spark-master/worker infrastructure (Pods) for running spark jobs, kubernetes under the hood will manage execution itself in cluster mode,1) will it effect any running applications, how much effective it is in terms of resource efficiency, if we compare spark-operator way 2) Also do i need to setup spark-operator env explicitly ( Helm is only way to do same ?)

Comment: 1. shouldn't, assuming you k8s cluster configured properly (auto-scaling nodes for example). Resource efficiency == optimal - that's the reason to run spark on top of k8s. I am not using the operator so I can't say (but it's mainly for submitting jobs via yaml). 2. can't say, that's a different question

Comment: @Zester07 if it solved your question, don't forget to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The real reason for the exception:

> java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: local

was that a Worker of the Spark Standalone cluster wanted to `downloadUserJar`, but simply didn't recognize `local` URI scheme.

This is because Spark Standalone does not understand it and, unless I'm mistaken, the only cluster environments that support this `local` URI scheme are Spark on YARN and Spark on Kubernetes.

And that's where you can connect the dots why this exception was sorted out by changing the master URL. Well, the OP wanted to deploy the Spark application to Kubernetes (and followed the rules for Spark on Kubernetes) while the master URL was `spark://192.XXX.XXX.XXX:7077` which is for Spark Standalone.